# maven build fails only in Jenkins - artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

A few days ago half of my Jenkins projects started failing with the same error. No changes had been made to any of these projects for several weeks or more (and they were all building fine previously).

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.970s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 22 11:44:06 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) on project vessel-stopped-detector: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) on project vessel-stopped-detector: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem.createArtifact(LegacyRepositorySystem.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.initProject(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:312)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:578)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieve(MavenMetadataSource.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:532)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:493)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveWithExceptions(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:349)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:343)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.artifact.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.artifact.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:436)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 31 more
```

If I log into the actual machine and run "mvn clean install" or "mvn dependency:tree" on any of the failing projects then this works and they build successfully.

Every dependency in the .pom files has a groupid

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs
            (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use Spring Expression
            APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- geotools dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- drool dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- drools dependencies, needed for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-daemon</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-daemon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Really not sure what the problem is here.

Jenkins ver. 1.615

Maven 3.1.1

Comment: Notice that the problem is with the assembly plugin. Are you using a fixed version of this plugin? is it possible that the version being used have changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this by restarting the Jenkins after deleting the m2 repo. The Jenkins process had to be killed as it wasn't responding to restart commands.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by completely truncating the .m2/repository directory (something was corrupt I guess)